# Factor simple cubic polynomial $ax^3 + cx + d = 0$

Tags: polynomials, roots, factoring, cubics

I'm working on a self-made problem where I have a cubic equation I need to factor. I have *some* flexibility in choosing my own coefficients for the polynomial, so I am strategically trying to choose my coefficients within the admissible set so that the cubic I end up with is simple to factor. What are the forms of some simple cubic equations to factor? For example, if the second coefficient is zero, so it is

$$ax^3 + cx + d = 0$$
is that simpler to factor than the general case? Any other examples? I'm not trying to solve for the general cubic, which is hard, I want to modify my cubic so that it is easy to factor. Thank you!

Comment: The formulas to find the roots of a cubic are explicit. The form of the cubic you are referring to is sometimes called "depressed." This [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) provides explicit formulas as well as a discussion of the form you have asked about.

Comment: Thank you @RyanK!

Answer (score 2):

For the cubic polynomial $ax^3+c x+d$ to factorize, its coefficients $a$, $c$ and $d$, assuming all rational, have to satisfy
$$d=-r(ar^2+c)$$
where $r$ is rational. Then, the polynomial factorizes as
$$ax^3+c x +d=a(x-r)(x^2+ r x +r^2 +\frac ca)$$

Comment: Is there something similar for 4th degree?

Comment: Wait. If $d=-r \left(a r^3+b r+c\right)$ then $$a x^4+b x^2+c x+d=(x-r) \left(a x^3+a r x^2+a r^2 x+bx+a r^3+b r+c\right)$$

Comment: @Raffaele - I guess it’s right. For example $x^4+x-2=(x-1)(x^3+x^2+x+2)$